# Как перебрать шаблон с переменным числом аргументов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Как перебрать шаблон с переменным числом аргументов?
грубо говоря есть функция

```
template <typname... T>
void test(T1... args) 
{

}
```

Как мне перебрать args?

Comment: что значит "перебрать"? сделать цикл?

Comment: @KoVadim, грубо говоря да, пройтись по всем значениям

Comment: Рекурсивно? Обработайте первый аргумент и вызовите себя с остатком списка

Comment: @KoVadim, можно пример пожалуйста

Comment: http://scrutator.me/post/2017/08/11/cpp17_lang_features_p1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так. Это называется [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
void test(T ...args) 
{
    ([&]{
        std::cout << args << '\n';
    }(), ...);
}

int main()
{
    test(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Лямбда вызывается N раз. Внутри нее `args` ссылается на очередной элемент `args...`.

---

В fold expression вместо `,` может быть любой бинарный оператор, например `+`.

Т.е. сумму всех аргументов можно получить так: `return (args + ...);`, или, если нужно, чтобы это работало для 0 аргументов, то так: `return (args + ... + 0);`.

---

Какая-то версия MSVC у меня давилась синтаксисом выше, но сейчас повторить не получается. Как обходной вариант работала лямбда с параметром `([&](auto x){...}(args), ...)`.