# Как обратится к параметрам шаблона с переменным количеством параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class... Other>
auto sum(T& first, Other... other)
{
    T mas[]={other...};
    cout << "size: " << sizeof...(other) << endl;
    for (int m: mas)
        first+=m;
    return first;
}

int main() {
    int summa = 0;
    sum(summa,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
    cout << "sum: " << summa << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Есть такой короткий кусок кода, который выводи следующее:

```
size: 7
sum: 28
```

Вопрос очень простой и хотелось бы получить такой же простой ответ:
Как мне обратится поэлементно к каждому параметру переменного числа аргументов `other`? Пытался создать указатель, да он постоянно жалуется, короче не знаю как это синтаксически выглядит.

Сразу оговорюсь, что меня не интересует как элементы разложить в массив, это я сам знаю, как именно мне обратиться к каждому элементу именно other..., а не mas[].

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: Очень похоже на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1406175/215103). Если это не то, что вам нужно, говорите.